# Windows RRAS - Multiple NICs, same subnet?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, rras

I currently have a server with 3 NICs, it is functioning as a router.

NIC1 = 10.7.93.1
NIC2 = 11.7.93.1
NIC3 = 12.7.93.1

NIC 1 is connected to an ISP router (will be direct WAN in the future) and also hands out DHCP to the rest of the units connected to the ISP router. NIC2 is connected to a switch that provides a section of the house with wired connections. NIC3 is connected to a wifi access point. The server provides DHCP/DNS for all three networks, and all three networks are unable to talk to each other, they can only access the internet through the server.

The issue is that I would like the NIC2 network with all the wired clients, to be able to talk to the network on NIC1. Preferably be on the same subnet (10.7.93.x) I just can't seem to get this to work and my knowledge about it doesn't seem enough. I'd rather avoid VPN. Is there anyone who could send me the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have such a complex setup? My initial suggestion would be to ditch this setup and connect all of the devices to the same physical network and give them all ip addresses in the same subnet.

Comment: @joeqwerty To separate work devices from home devices and to separate guest wifi from the rest of the network. In case anything happens to the wifi, my work-related devices are on a separate network, unaffected. This also allows me to divide bandwidth. The router runs Hyper-V, where I connect some consumer services like Plex to the non-work networks, but other servers are only available for the work-network. I have recently opted to just bridge the two connections, whenever I need connectivity between the work and home network temporarily for file transfers.

Comment: https://www.think-like-a-computer.com/2011/08/24/ip-routing/ might help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm obviously a little late for this answer to be useful to you.  But for anyone else...

You don't need VPN to achieve this.

What you're looking for can be enabled with netsh.

You first need to get the correct interface names.  Sometimes you can use index numbers with netsh but the commands we're going to be using need names. So grab them here:

**netsh interface show interface**

Then you need to install the NAT feature:

**netsh routing ip nat install**

Enable NAT for the NIC1 network (servers being communicated to):

**netsh routing ip nat add interface "NIC1 (or interface name)" full**

Enable NAT masquerade for the NIC2 network (clients communicating from):

**netsh routing ip nat add interface "NIC2" private**

Lastly, make sure the gateway address for clients in the NIC2 network is 11.7.93.1

Job done!